# Select words that are in a vector multiple times

Tags: r

I stored some items that didn't fulfill a criteria in a vector.

```
non.fulfilled <- c('positive', 'beta.1', 'beta.2', 'negative', 'alpha.1', 'alpha.2', 'alpha.3')
```

Now, I would like to find which words are in my vector multiple times and afterwards add them to this vector. So in this case:

```
non.fulfilled2 <- cbind(non.fulfilled, 'beta', 'alpha')
```

How do I find these words?

Comment: What do you mean? None of them are unique. Also, you have a vector, not a list

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry for the confusion... I changed my question now

Comment: How do you define which vector appear multiple times? 'beta.1' is different than 'beta.2'. Do you just remove everything after `.` ?

Comment: Yes, so the string that comes before the dot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to keep string before dot, count their occurrence using `table` and select values which occur more than once.

```
vals <- table(sub('\\..*', '', non.fulfilled))
names(vals[vals > 1])
#[1] "alpha" "beta"
```

Append them to original vector

```
c(non.fulfilled, names(vals[vals > 1]))
```

Answer (score 3):

If we assume that a "word" here is defined as the first run of `\w` ("word characters"), we can do as follows to get the desired output:

```r
non.fulfilled <- c('positive', 'beta.1', 'beta.2', 'negative', 'alpha.1', 'alpha.2', 'alpha.3')

library(stringr)

words <- str_extract(non.fulfilled, "\\w+")
unique(words[duplicated(words)])
#> [1] "beta"  "alpha"
```

EDIT: After clarification in the comments, we can get duplicates like so:

```r
words <- str_replace(non.fulfilled, "\\..*", "")
unique(words[duplicated(words)])
#> [1] "beta"  "alpha"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `tidyverse` approaches

```
library(dplyr)    
library(stringr)
tibble(non.fulfilled) %>% 
   mutate(non.fulfilled = str_remove(non.fulfilled, "\\.\\d+$")) %>% 
   count(non.fulfilled) %>%
   filter(n > 1) %>%
   pull(non.fulfilled)
#[1] "alpha" "beta"
```